# Prevent adding class without browser scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

This *js* add class only while Scroll Up the browser page. But problem is after Scroll Up browser to top of the page `.darkHeader` class are not remove, means i want to remove this class after page Scroll Up to top.

**JS**

```
lastScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x3hpra4/2/) >>

How to remove `.darkHeader` class after page has completely scroll Up on top of page/head? How to prevent adding class without browser scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another condition which checks if the scrolling is at the top of the page, and removes the class like this:

```
    if(scroll === 0){
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
```

Comment: The dark header is still showing when you scroll back up to the top of the page? What browser are you using?  And are you sure you implemented it correctly (here's a forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/ )?

Comment: woo works, thanks, now i have try it on my site :) on more is it works in IE9? thanks.